# Azure func project for nodejs not deploying from DevOps Pipelines but deployes from local

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-eventgrid

Consider this az func project for nodejs with the following functions with 3 different bindings: cosmosdb, eventgrid and http

```js
app.cosmosDB('forwardInvoiceOutEventsToTopic', {
  ...COSMOSDB_DEFAULT_CONFIG_WITH_LEASE,
  containerName: 'invoice-out-events',
  leaseContainerPrefix: 'forwardToTopic',
  maxItemsPerInvocation: 5,
  retry: DEFAULT_RETRY,
  handler: (document) => {console.log('this has a real implementation')}
})
app.eventGrid('invoiceOutGenerateDocument', {
  handler: (event) => {console.log('this has a real implementation')},
  return: output.cosmosDB({
    ...COSMOSDB_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
    containerName: 'invoice-out-events',
    createIfNotExists: false,
    connectionStringSetting: 'COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING',
    collectionName: 'invoice-out-events'
  })
})
app.http('sandboxInsertInvoiceOut', {
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  handler: (request) => {console.log('this has a real implementation')},
})
```

also the `hosts.json` file for the project

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cosmosDB": {
      "connectionMode": "Gateway",
      "protocol": "Https"
    },
    "eventGrid": {
      "maxConcurrentCallsPerWorker": 1
    },
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "",
      "maxOutstandingRequests": 200,
      "maxConcurrentRequests": 100,
      "dynamicThrottlesEnabled": true,
      "hsts": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxAge": "10"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

All the infrastructure necessary is deployed already using terraform. Deploying the function project from the local machine works as a charm, functions get properly invoked with each document written to the respective container or each event properly filtered into the event grid subscription.

However, while deploying the same project through the Azure DevOps Pipelines, the functions are not deployed and the previously deployed instances from the local machine are deleted.

```yaml
 # REST OF THE PIPELINE FILE 
          - script: |
              if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
              then
                  dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
              fi
              npm install && npm run build && npm run test && npm prune --production
            displayName: 'Build and test'

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: 'Archive files'
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              artifactName: 'drop'

          - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
            displayName: 'Deploy to Staging'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppBaseName)-staging
              package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: "NODE|18"
              deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
```

Looping through the logs I find this log message in case of the failure from the pipeline deployment

```
No job functions found. 
Try making your job classes and methods public. 
If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) 
make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code 
(e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

From the local deployment I can find this log message which I can not see in case of the pipeline deployment

```
registered EventGrid Endpoint = https://<storage-account-name>.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid
```

Both `host.json` and `package.json` are present in the build archive from the pipeline and the `main` in `package.json` points to the correct path

```json
"main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
```

The azure app settings from the azure function:

```json
{
  "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
  "FUNCTIONS_NODE_BLOCK_ON_ENTRY_POINT_ERROR": "true",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
  "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "workers-app-staging-9180",
  "WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE": "false",
  "WEBSITE_MOUNT_ENABLED": "1",
  "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "18",
  "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1702637293722.zip?XXXXXXX"
}
```

So now I am stuck a bit, not finding anything in the documentation files that would help me safely deploy this from the pipeline, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the App settings "**`WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1`**" to your Azure Function App to fix the issue:

1. In terraform file, you can set the App settings like as below. Also can reference "[**azurerm_function_app**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#argument-reference)".

   ```
   resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
     name = "example-azure-function"
     . . .

     app_settings {
       WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1
     }
   }
   ```
2. On the web page of Azure Portal, you can set the App settings by navigating to the Function App > **Configuration** > **Application settings**.

   [image]

---

Related documentations:

- [**App settings reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_run_from_package)
- [**Run from package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package)

---

Comment: Weirdly enough the pipeline will update the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE setting when running

Comment: Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'xxxx'
The Deployment Type option does not apply for Linux Consumption.
Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1702632360413.zip?***"}
Updated App Service Application settings.
Updated WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Application setting to https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1702632360413.zip?***
Syncing triggers for function app
Sync triggers for function app completed successfully

Comment: @GeorgeE, How about setting the **`deploymentMethod`** to **`zipDeploy`**?

Comment: Same behavior. I've added the in the original post the app_setings picked out from the azure console maybe there is some misalignment there

Comment: Also forgot to mention that this is a linux app function on the consumption plan